# Multiple c:imports with Stripes is causing problems

Tags: jstl, stripes, dynamic-import

I'm having a problem when I call the same Stripes action with multiple c:import tags in the same jsp.  When I use the first c:import, I use a few c:params with it.  These get bound to the corresponding fields in the action.  But then when I use the next c:import, the fields are already set from the first c:import, which is not what I want.  I want to be able to import an action several times, and each time it should only use the values I pass in with the c:param tags.

The only solution I could think of is to call a method before binding and validation takes place, that sets all the fields to null.  Is that a bad idea?  What's the best way to handle this?

```
    <c:import url="/widget/House.action">
        <c:param name="dogNam" value="Muffin" />
        <c:param name="catName" value="Junior" />
    </c:import>

    <c:import url="/widget/House.action">
        <c:param name="dogNam" value="Rocky" />
    </c:import>
```

In this example catName is getting set to "Junior" both the first and second time I use the c:import.

Comment: Btw, I think this behavior is because Stripes is using the same instance of the class both times because its all in the same request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The c:import fires an http request to your Java application server and from what you describe the second c:import still seems to add the `catName` parameters to the request, you might want to try this:

```
<c:import url="/widget/House.action">
    <c:param name="dogNam" value="Rocky" />
    <c:param name="catNam" value="" />
</c:import>
```

Comment: What if I have a list of arbitrary size as one of the fields on the class?  I would use tags that look like this <c:param name="catNames[0]" value="Junior" />  I might have 1 of those, or I might have 100.  How would I know how many to set to empty string?

Comment: If above fixed your problem, you might first want to check what actually causes this bug. It could be a bug in your Java web container. To check you could try to run your code on a different web container. Or maybe it’s caused by your setup, could be something like a caching proxy in front of your web container / web server.